# How to capitalize specific uppercase words in vim

Tags: vim, uppercase, capitalize

We have a 5000-line text file containing words like so:

```
BANKS
BEING AFRAID OF DOGS
This is a SENTENCE.
Just another sentence.
COUNTRY
```

Using `vim`, I want to capitalize the words only in the lines where all the words are in uppercase (meaning lines 3 and 4 should be left untouched). In other words, what I expect to get is:

```
Banks
Being Afraid Of Dogs
This is a SENTENCE.
Just another sentence.
Country
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nothing yet. Most of the solutions I found so far explained how to capitalize each word which takes a long time for me to do so one by one.

Comment: There are two parts to your problem: 1. "do something on each UPPERCASE line",
2. "Capitalize the word on a line", that you should address separately.

Comment: @romainl I can say: 1. find lines where all words are uppercase, then 2. capitalize every word on that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring to [Power of g](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g) and [Switching_case_of_characters](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters).

1. Applying the command to line containing upper case character and space only, which is `g/^[A-Z ]*$/`
2. Then do [Title case](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters#Title_case) conversion `s/\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>/\u\1\L\2/g`

The whole command will be
`:g/^[A-Z ]*$/s/\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>/\u\1\L\2/g`

Comment: The only situation where I've been using `g` was in `:g/PATTERN/d` unfortunately! Thanks. That helped.